# Customer Identification - additional fields

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

We are doing a call with CustInq on Silverlake and know to add **x_TaxDetail** for that sort of additional information, but are there other calls we should make instead, or **XtendElem** items we should add, in order to retrieve customer identification fields such as drivers license, passport number, or state IDs? Additionally, we'd like to retrieve mother's maiden name for the customer ID provided.

Having this will add to the verification process.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This information can be found on the CustInq API message brief. (https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/custinq/)

The X_Identify XtendElem will provide identification information.

We do not capture mother's maiden name as a default but a bank may elect to use a User Defined Field for that purpose.